# How to make Flask-WTF Validate Override execute properly

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a simple form which contains a `URLField` and `StringField`. As shown below:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import URLField
#from flask.ext.wtf.html5 import URLField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, url

class BookmarkForm(Form):
    url = URLField('url')
    description = StringField('description')

    # override validate method of Form class for custom validation

    def validate(self):
        #app.logger.debug('Inside validate')
        if not self.url.data.startswith("http://") or\
            self.url.data.startswith("https://"):
            self.url.data = "http://" + self.url.data

        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False

        if not self.description:
            self.description.data = self.url.data

        return True
```

#### This is how its handled in view

```
@app.route('/add', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    #form = BookmarkForm(request.form)
    form = BookmarkForm()
    #if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.url.data
        description = form.description.data

        bm = models.Bookmark(url=url, description=description) # push to table
        db.session.add(bm)
        db.session.commit()

        # store_bookmarks(url,description) # old method

        flash("Stored '{}' '{}' ".format(url,description))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```

**But, what is causing the validate override to not execute?**

Comment: Do you call `form.validate()` [inside your view](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/#in-the-view)?

Comment: Yes . I am making this call in view.
    if form.validate_on_submit():
           url = form.url.data

Comment: Can you show how you instantiate `BookmarkForm` in your view?

Comment: @ SeanVieira , I have added the view code in the original question.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same/similar issue where only the first conditio would be evaulated in this code

```
if not self.url.data.startswith("http://") or\
        self.url.data.startswith("https://"):
        self.url.data = "http://" + self.url.data
```

You need add () for the OR logic:

```
    if not (self.url.data.startswith("http://") or\
        self.url.data.startswith("https://")):
        self.url.data = "http://" + self.url.data
```